# How to use plugin in nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I am getting Unexpected Identifier while trying to use plugin countup.

I tried to declare the plugin like this
  { src: '~/plugins/vue-countup.js', ssr: false}

and globally registered the component by getting separate .js file

Getting Unexpected Identifer error while the cmd window shows 0 errors

```
plugins: [

  { src: '~/plugins/vue-countup.js', ssr: false}
  ],
build: {

   transpile: [
     'countup.js'
    ],
    extend(config, ctx) {
    }
  }

import Vue from 'vue';
import ICountUp from 'vue-countup-v2'

Vue.component(ICountUp.name, ICountUp)
```

Showing Unexpected Identifier error on the window.
[image]

Comment: Show full error stack

Comment: I have added the image in my question. Can you please check. If I register ICountup locally then it is showing this error.